# i18n and Forms with playframework 2.4.x using Java

Tags: java, forms, scala, playframework, internationalization

I'm playing with a form and getting various errors related to internationalization, depending on what 'fix' I attempt.

I should mention I'm working on eclipse with Scala IDE for Eclipse (http://scala-ide.org/).

I've configured my play to use Java. Of course, the template files are still 'Scala' so when it comes to the documentation and they are talking about 'Scala', I'm often not sure if it applies to my case.

To be more precise, the migration instructions 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24
talk about using a Messages value instead of Lang. In this case, I don't think this applies to me, as 1. I'm not actually migrating, and 2. I'm using a Java Play app. Below, it mentions that for Java there is not much to do.

OK, I wanted to create a Form. I set out about this with the "help" of the documentation:  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaFormHelpers

However, I get my first problem with the line:
@helper.inputText(myForm("email"))

I see the error (in eclipse)

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit handler: views.html.helper.FieldConstructor, implicit messages: 
     play.api.i18n.Messages)play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class inputText. Unspecified value parameter messages.
    - could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
```

The full text is:

```
@* loadPatients Template File *@
@(loadForm: Form[models.Patient])
@import play.i18n._

@main("Load Patients to Database") {
    @Messages.get("global.greeting")
    @helper.form(action = routes.Utils.loadPatientsAction()) {
        @helper.inputText(loadForm("path"))     
    }
}
```

However, the app seems to be compiling (command line) and I can load the page.

Incidentally, it is the same error I see if I attempt to use the 'scala' version of the Messages class:

```
@import play.api.i18n.Messages

@Messages("global.greeting")
```

So, instead of generating i18n messages in that way, I use

```
@Messages.get("global.greeting")
```

It seems I'm working with a version of Playframework which is on the cusp of some major changes. The documentation is sparse or incorrect
i.e., https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaI18N
specifies we can use the Scala Messages object within templates by importing play.i18n.Messages and using the form:

```
@Messages("hello")
```

which seems to be incorrect!!! (it would only work, in principle, by importing play.api.i18n.Messages)

The error I am seeing now in eclipse (and not in the console) is most likely Scala IDE related (rather than a real problem of my Play app) right ??

**My main question is:**

Given all the changes with internationalization in play 2.4.x, am I creating and using this Form, and using Internationalization the 'correct' and up-to-date way for this (play 2.4.x) and near future versions?

Comment: About the problem, I use successfully java version of i18n in play 2.4 and 2.5. Your question is a very wide and better to divide they to few sub questions.

Comment: Yes, perhaps, Sorry. I see so many "related" problems, it seems difficult sometimes difficult to separate them. Yet, most of the text is meant to be just background or context to the 'main' question; of, is the code block above correct for play 2.5? Given a 'Yes' for that, I could assume a bug in Scala IDE and (apart from maybe filing a bug report there) move on. If the answer is 'no', then I would like to know what the current "preferred" and up-to-date method is.

Comment: Incidentally, I've since had a look at the HTML code generated by the helper, and it seems it is probably something I may but don't have to use. Not necessarily the ideal thing to do. I'm still learning this, and want to ensure I write code that is both more maintainable, and more portable. I guess I should not use helper. I avoid the above mentioned problem, and I have more control over the HTML generated. But that is probably a topic for another question which probably has no good answer.

Comment: Actually I ended up with my own helpers as well. I review the code of the default helpers and the way how to create custom helpers on them. And ... decide that there are a lot of different abstractions for just a few lines of html. So I just create some sub templates for my fields and use them in my projects. Another benefit - it is much simple to change them for the front end developer then the defaults one.